# while exporting file from database to csv,it gives displays content in the row of table column name

Tags: php, mysql

While exporting file to csv,my contents are added in the same row of column names.I want content just below to the respective columns.The code is as follow

```
     <?php
        $filename = "file.csv";
        $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');           
        header('Content-type: application/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
        $headerLine = 'Sr. No,Name,DOB,Address';
        fwrite($fp, $headerLine);
         $query = "select * from registratin";
        $result = mssql_query($query);
        $i = 1;
        while($row = mssql_fetch_row($result)) {
          $row = array_merge(array($i), $row);
          fputcsv($fp, $row);
          $i++;
        }

      ?>
```

Comment: What database is this? Your code says mssql you have tagged mysql?

Comment: The write a new line after the headers: `fwrite($fp, $headerLine . PHP_EOL);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply as follows , there is no need to array merge

```
<?php
        $filename = "file.csv";
        $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');           
        header('Content-type: application/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
        $headerLine = 'Sr. No,Name,DOB,Address';
        fputcsv($fp, explode(",",$headerLine); // adding heading
        $query = "select * from registratin";
        $result = mssql_query($query);
        $i = 1;
        while($row = mssql_fetch_row($result)) {
          //$row = array_merge(array($i), $row); ***no need***
          fputcsv($fp, $row);
          $i++;
        }
        fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: For adding header I am using fwrite($fp,$headerLine) because I don't want fieldname Sr. No to be like "Sr. No".But because i am using fwrite my contents are just next to the same row of column name

Comment: is your problem solved now ??what you wanted to achieve above solution is just doing same

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use `mysqli`, and this is the simple way to get the work done.
And in `select` choose only required columns.

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

fputcsv($output, array('SR No', 'Name','DOB','Address'));

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password',"database");
$rows = mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT * from registration');

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows))
    fputcsv($output, $row);
```